# How can I brick the Android emulator?

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator

I'm working on a master's thesis and want to demonstrate how bad a malicious application can be.  I'm looking for a pre-installed application on the application on the android emulator or an application that has "brick" permission on the device. Rather than bricking my device, I would much prefer bricking the emulator instead!

PS: My device is a samsung galaxy i7500 just in case.

EDIT: Please do care to leave a comment as to why this question might annoy you (I promise not to serial downvote you)!  I understand the topic may seem "very suspicious", but then I would not be linking myself publically to something that may be malicious in nature and I intend to pull off! Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Bricking the device means rending it unusable? Why would you do that?

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: All reasons I can think of for using such a feature would be malicious. So even if I knew I would not tell you.

Comment: Need it for my Masters thesis presentation to show in a demonstration how dangerous a malicious application can be... =) I know what bricking is, its purely academic...

Comment: To be honest, there will be be no way of doing something like that. Maybe if the device is rooted you might be able to remove something critical and then cause the phone not to boot, but it would be simple enough to fix.

Maybe you should just explain it and say that there isn't a know way of doing it but if there's a bug somewhere in the framework (very likely) it might be possible.

Comment: I guess removing something for phone not booting would be an okay way to fake it, but doubt will be able to pull it off. I mean I have to literally fiddle around with the app to show how it destroys my phone! But its surprising, none of the apps use this permission!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't find any apps on the Android Market that do this. Just try the code for yourself:

`Not granting permission android.permission.BRICK to package com.example.app (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x4444)`

Only applications with the same signature as the system can use the `BRICK` permission ([protectionLevel=2](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.java;h=3cc884b1098aeef44126d18414f63bd3a5faf6c9;hb=HEAD#l43)).

You'd need to [build the Android platform](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) yourself in order to attempt this.

See also [BrickReceiver](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/BrickReceiver.java;h=cff3805b68d2363fa69280fcfbaefadd755f5abe;hb=HEAD) for an example of how it supposedly should work.

Comment: So basically the report published by SMobile http://threatcenter.smobilesystems.com/?p=1887. That there are 8 applications in the market place that are capable of bricking a phone, false?

Comment: That an app *requests* the permission doesn't mean that the system will *grant* it, as per my example above. I'd imagine that's what's happening here.

Comment: Okay, this is news to me! If an application requests for a permission, the system can deny it at install time, yet the application will be installed onto the device?

Comment: Yes, the "Not granting permission" snippet I posted above was logged by the device when I tried to install an app with BRICK permission. The app is installed; it'll just fail at runtime if you try to use that permission.

Comment: Thanks will accept your answer if I don't get a response in another couple of days. For now I will give you a +1. Thanks.

Comment: I can not belive that call exist.

Comment: @Macarse - Ummm, care to elaborate? are you referring to the answer or just expressing your surprise?

Comment: @Shouvik: Just expressing my surprise  :)

Comment: @Christopher: Seven words: OMFG WTF! hehe :)

Comment: If its true then on searching the installed apps on my device, I should technically find this app!? do I need to root my device for this app to turn up bcoz I can see all the system apps.

Comment: Sorry, which app are you're expecting to see?

Comment: ha ha, guess what I found... :) http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/allpermissions_hniq.html

Comment: Yup, and when you install it 56 of the 114 requested permissions are refused by the phone.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Appreciate it.